# How to Enable CoffeeScript Editing in VS2012 Update 2?

Tags: visual-studio, coffeescript

It used to work from Web Essentials until the author of that extension took out support.

I'm completely up-to-date on Visual Studio updates, but for whatever reason, CoffeeScript does not get transpiled to JavaScript when I save, and the editor doesn't offer me side-by-side preview of the resulting JavaScript.  Is there anything special I have to do to turn this on?

Comment: Running the latest web essentials and with VS 2012 Update 2 works fine for me with CoffeeScript. If you are running the latest of everything, check your compilation settings under Tools, Options, Web Essentials, CoffeeScript, check the "Generate JavaScript on save" settings.

Comment: But I thought CoffeeScript support was ripped out of Web Essentials.  Are you saying that I still need Web Essentials?

Comment: The WebEssentials February 17 2013 release note contains the line item: "Removed LESS/CoffeeScript editors"

Comment: Although, when I reinstall Web Essentials (which I had installed when I started down this path), it works now.  I'm incredibly frustrated by the poor communication from that product.  Anyway, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

CoffeeScript compilation is still in Web Essentials - not in VS Update 2.